# Selecting an Item in GridView with ITemplate Generated Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, itemplate

I'm having trouble figuring out how could I use my imagebutton (see below) in my ITemplate to append the button's corresponding row data (ItemID) as a query string.

My ImageButton in my ITemplate:

```
ImageButton select_button = new ImageButton();
select_button.ID = "select_button";
select_button.ImageUrl = "~/Files/System/Icons/highlighter.png";
select_button.CommandName = "Select";
select_button.ToolTip = "Select";
container.Controls.Add(select_button);
```

Should I handle it in in the imagebutton's OnClick event (if so, is there a way to get the row where the button is located) or can I handle in in the GridView events (rowbinding, rowseleted, rowcommand, etc.)?

I'd be glad to elaborate more on my code upon request. ^ ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the ID in the `CommandArgument` property of your button control in the `RowDataBound` Event.  Once you have an ID, you can track rows with it.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRow dr = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        ((Button)e.Row.FindControl("select_button")).CommandArgument = dr["IdColumn"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I can add the id as the command argument in my page with the example you gave me ^ ^